# How to find WebCam

Tags: c#, .net, video, video-capture, expression-encoder-sdk

There is a very good [solution how to use WebCam via MS Expression Encoder SDK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control).

So this code

```
 Dim vidDevices = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video)
```

returns the list of the installed video devices.

My question is: how to get WebCam as device by default. Is it possible to return /filter only first installed WebCam and no more?

I mean I don't care how many video devices installed I just need get one of the WebCam and that's it.

Is it possible to automate it somehow or we have to select device manually anyway?

Comment: http://haryoktav.wordpress.com/2009/03/21/webcam-in-c-aforgenet/ Read this article. Perhaps it help.

Comment: Thank you! It was helpful! Also I found that there is \AForge.NET\Framework\Samples\Video\Two Cameras Test  It is exactly what I need.